Emacs, How to bind a custom compile command to a key?
In my .emacs file,I want to pass the current buffer file name to an external bash compile script called, "com", and bind it to a keyboard key, preferably, Ctrl-F5.
I have tried several attempts without success.  Not an expert on the syntax of the .emacs file.

This is probably more suitable for emacs.stackexchange.com.
